# Excel Macro / Module assistance - How to write a code to autofit Cell width

Tags: excel, vba, module

I got a module/macro for Excel form this site: [Macro to send email of Excel content][1] The macro works, except the cells are too small for large amount of data in each cell, how do i write a script within the code to adjust the width of the cell accordingly with the data that is inside the cell. The cells vary in terms of the amount of data. Thanks!

```
Sub Send_Row()
      ' Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
      ' Working in Office 2000-2010
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Ash As Worksheet

Set Ash = ActiveSheet
On Error GoTo cleanup
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

For Each cell In Ash.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "yes" Then

        Ash.Range("A1:AE100").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Value

        With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "CSI"
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
            .Display  'Or use Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Next cell

       cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
      End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include the link ...?

Answer (score 0):

I use

`Excel.Rows.AutoFit`

and

`Excel.Columns.AutoFit`

to make the worksheet cells automatically adjust themselves to the best height and width for their content.

You can call these two lines of code anywhere in your code, but I would do it just before creating the email.

As an alternative, if you wanted to do it manually, I use these shortcut keys:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - autofit columns
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - autofit rows